# Bouncycastle crashes during EC/RSA certificate verification

Tags: java, bouncycastle, x509

I have an X509 RSA certificate emitted by a EC root, this code:

```
certificate.verify(certificate.getPublicKey());
```

Fails with this error:

> cannot identify EC public key.

EC is the algorithm used to SIGN the certificate.

Comment: It seems you're trying to verify certificate using it's own key (probably RSA), instead of signer key

Comment: Yes it is, in this case i am check if a certificate is self signed

Comment: How can a self signed cert have an RSA key and sign itself with an EC key ?

Comment: This test is generic, of course a self signed certificate is RSA or EC but if i use as _certificate_ a certificate wth RSA key but issued by a EC certificate i obtain this error

Answer (score 0):

You have a RSA cert that has been signed using an EC key.

You are verifying this cert passing the certificate public key (RSA) as the publicKey associated with the privateKey that signed the cert (that was EC).

This is not the correct public key to verify the cert.
You should use as parameter of verify() the EC public key associated with the EC private key that signed the cert.